# Separate readSream / writeStream vs DuplexStream differences?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

Assuming we're creating an our own custom readable/writeable stream by inheriting from the Stream class. In the first scenario, we use the `Readable` and the `Writable` classes:

```js
const Stream = require("stream");

const readableStream = new Stream.Readable();

readableStream._read = (size) => {
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    readableStream.push(`${i},`);
  }
  readableStream.push(null);
};

const writeableStream = new Stream.Writable();

writeableStream._write = (chunk, encoding, next) => {
  console.log("writeableStream", chunk.toString());
  next();
};

readableStream.pipe(writeableStream);
```

In the second scenario, we use the Duplex class (which inherits from both Readable/Writable):

```js
const { Duplex } = require("stream");

const myDuplexStream = new Duplex();

myDuplexStream._read = (size) => {
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    myDuplexStream.push(`${i},`);
  }
  myDuplexStream.push(null);
};

myDuplexStream._write = (chunk, encoding, next) => {
  if (Buffer.isBuffer(chunk)) {
    chunk = chunk.toString();
  }
  console.log("write operation", chunk);
};

myDuplexStream.pipe(myDuplexStream); // that's I guess a no-go but we could just use a plain on("readable") event.
```

Would these 2 implementation be practically equal?

Answer (score 1):

**No, they’re not identical.**

(A) The first example shows a scenario where integers are pushed to a writable buffer that pipe its data to a writable sink. I.e:

1. Integers are pushed to a readable buffer
2. The readable pipe its data to a writable buffer
3. The write stream will console.log the data

(B) While the second example shows a quirky scenario where data piped into the duplex is logged to the console. And, unrelated to any input, some integers are pushed to a readable buffer each time some other stream calls read() on the duplex. I.e:

1. (Some unknown source must write/pipe data to the duplex)
2. The duplex console.logs the streamed input
3. (no data is forwarded from the duplex writable to the duplex readable, instead a list of integers is pushed to the readable buffer when a subsequent writable calls read())
4. When a stream writable calls read() on the duplex, it will push the integers 1-9 to the readable buffer, for the writable to consume stream. Then it will close the readable side of the duplex (due to `push(null)`).

The writable of a duplex handles the incoming data, while the readable provides the the outgoing data. (B) seems to have mixed up the order of the readable/writable in the duplex class.

The OP's Duplex example should probably be:

```js
const { Duplex } = require("stream");

const myDuplexStream = new Duplex();
myDuplexStream.chunkProcessingBuffer = []

myDuplexStream._write = (chunk, encoding, next) => {
  console.log("this is my incoming chunk:", chunk.toString());
  // Typically, this chunk would be processed in some way before pushing it to the readable interface
  chunkProcessingBuffer.push(chunk);
  next();
};

myDuplexStream._read = (size) => {
  // The readable interface would typically push more than one chunk at the time for each call to read()
  console.log("this is my outgoing chunk:", chunk.toString());
  myDuplexStream.push(chunkProcessingBuffer.shift());
};


const readableStream = new Stream.Readable();

readableStream._read = (size) => {
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    readableStream.push(`${i},`);
  }
  readableStream.push(null);
};

const writeableStream = new Stream.Writable();

writeableStream._write = (chunk, encoding, next) => {
  console.log("writeableStream", chunk.toString());
  next();
};

readableStream.pipe(myDuplexStream).pipe(writableStream)
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to write this! could you elaborate on "  `// The readable interface would typically push more than one chunk at the time for each call to read()"` why?

Comment: Happy to help. Let me explain with an example; the readable will typically read multiple chunks from a big data source. The stream.Writable will initially call read() once on the readable, and if the writable can process the data at the same frequency (or faster) than the readable, the read() function will only be called once. However, the faster the readable, the more likely is it that the readable can fill up the writable’s buffer - which in turn will trigger “backpressure”, and cause the writable to call read() once it’s ready for more data.